# BugZilla XML RPC Interface

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, perl, bugzilla

I am attempting to setup BugZilla to receive bug reports from another system using the XML-RPC interface.

BugZilla works fine on its own with its own interface.

When I attempt to test the XML-RPC functionality by accessing "xmlrpc.cgi" in my browser I get the error:

```
The XML-RPC Interface feature is not available in this Bugzilla
 at C:\BugZilla\xmlrpc.cgi line 27
    main::BEGIN(...) called at C:\BugZilla\xmlrpc.cgi line 29
    eval {...} called at C:\BugZilla\xmlrpc.cgi line 29
```

Following this, I install test-taint package from the default Perl repository, version 1.04. Re-running "xmlrpc.cgi" gives me an IIS error:

```
502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.
```

So I run the checksetup.pl which informs me that:

```
Use of uninitialized value in open at C:/Perl/site/lib/Test/Taint.pm line 334, <DATA> line 558.
```

Installing Test-Taint from CPAN is the same. I assume XML-RPC is reliant on Test-Taint, but Test-Taint doesn't seem to run correctly.

If I ignore this error and attempt to invoke "bz_webservice_demo.pl" to add an entry the script times out.

How can I get the XML-RPC / Test-Taint function working ?

Current Setup: IIS7.5 on Windows Server 2008
Bugzilla 4.2.2
Perl 5.14.2

```
C:\BugZilla>perl checksetup.pl
Set up gcc environment - 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
* This is Bugzilla 4.2.2 on perl 5.14.2
* Running on Win2008 Build 6002 (Service Pack 2)

Checking perl modules...
Checking for               CGI.pm (v3.51)     ok: found v3.59
Checking for           Digest-SHA (any)       ok: found v5.62
Checking for             TimeDate (v2.21)     ok: found v2.24
Checking for             DateTime (v0.28)     ok: found v0.76
Checking for    DateTime-TimeZone (v0.79)     ok: found v1.48
Checking for                  DBI (v1.614)    ok: found v1.622
Checking for     Template-Toolkit (v2.22)     ok: found v2.24
Checking for           Email-Send (v2.16)     ok: found v2.198
Checking for           Email-MIME (v1.904)    ok: found v1.911
Checking for                  URI (v1.37)     ok: found v1.59
Checking for       List-MoreUtils (v0.22)     ok: found v0.33
Checking for    Math-Random-ISAAC (v1.0.1)    ok: found v1.004
Checking for                Win32 (v0.35)     ok: found v0.44
Checking for            Win32-API (v0.55)     ok: found v0.64

Checking available perl DBD modules...
Checking for               DBD-Pg (v1.45)     ok: found v2.18.1
Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.001)    ok: found v4.021
Checking for           DBD-SQLite (v1.29)     ok: found v1.33
Checking for           DBD-Oracle (v1.19)     ok: found v1.30

The following Perl modules are optional:
Checking for                   GD (v1.20)     ok: found v2.46
Checking for                Chart (v2.1)      ok: found v2.4.5
Checking for          Template-GD (any)       ok: found v1.56
Checking for           GDTextUtil (any)       ok: found v0.86
Checking for              GDGraph (any)       ok: found v1.44
Checking for           MIME-tools (v5.406)    ok: found v5.503
Checking for          libwww-perl (any)       ok: found v6.02
Checking for             XML-Twig (any)       ok: found v3.41
Checking for          PatchReader (v0.9.6)    ok: found v0.9.6
Checking for            perl-ldap (any)       ok: found v0.44
Checking for          Authen-SASL (any)       ok: found v2.15
Checking for           RadiusPerl (any)       ok: found v0.20
Checking for            SOAP-Lite (v0.712)    ok: found v0.715
Checking for             JSON-RPC (any)       ok: found v0.96
Checking for              JSON-XS (v2.0)      ok: found v2.32
Use of uninitialized value in open at C:/Perl/site/lib/Test/Taint.pm line 334, <DATA> line 558.
Checking for           Test-Taint (any)       ok: found v1.04
Checking for          HTML-Parser (v3.67)     ok: found v3.68
Checking for        HTML-Scrubber (any)       ok: found v0.09
Checking for               Encode (v2.21)     ok: found v2.44
Checking for        Encode-Detect (any)       not found
Checking for Email-MIME-Attachment-Stripper (any)       ok: found v1.316
Checking for          Email-Reply (any)       ok: found v1.202
Checking for          TheSchwartz (any)       not found
Checking for       Daemon-Generic (any)       not found
Checking for             mod_perl (v1.999022) not found
Checking for     Apache-SizeLimit (v0.96)     not found
***********************************************************************
* OPTIONAL MODULES                                                    *
***********************************************************************
* Certain Perl modules are not required by Bugzilla, but by           *
* installing the latest version you gain access to additional         *
* features.                                                           *
*                                                                     *
* The optional modules you do not have installed are listed below,    *
* with the name of the feature they enable. Below that table are the  *
* commands to install each module.                                    *
***********************************************************************
*      MODULE NAME * ENABLES FEATURE(S)                               *
***********************************************************************
*    Encode-Detect * Automatic charset detection for text attachments *
*      TheSchwartz * Mail Queueing                                    *
*   Daemon-Generic * Mail Queueing                                    *
*         mod_perl * mod_perl                                         *
* Apache-SizeLimit * mod_perl                                         *
***********************************************************************
COMMANDS TO INSTALL OPTIONAL MODULES:

  Encode-Detect: ppm install Encode-Detect
    TheSchwartz: ppm install TheSchwartz
 Daemon-Generic: ppm install Daemon-Generic
       mod_perl: ppm install mod_perl
Apache-SizeLimit: ppm install Apache-SizeLimit

Reading ./localconfig...

OPTIONAL NOTE: If you want to be able to use the 'difference between two
patches' feature of Bugzilla (which requires the PatchReader Perl module
as well), you should install patchutils from:

    http://cyberelk.net/tim/patchutils/

Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.001)    ok: found v4.021
Checking for                MySQL (v5.0.15)   ok: found v5.5.27

WARNING: You need to set the max_allowed_packet parameter in your MySQL
configuration to at least 3276750. Currently it is set to 3275776.
You can set this parameter in the [mysqld] section of your MySQL
configuration file.

Removing existing compiled templates...
Precompiling templates...done.
checksetup.pl complete.
```

Comment: Any specific reason for using XML-RPC with bugzilla instead of REST API? -- https://wiki.mozilla.org/index.php?title=Bugzilla:REST_API:Methods&oldid=281673

Comment: Unfortunately it's what the 3rd party app uses which we're doing the integrating with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out this is a known bug.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=708252